# Is it possible to prepopulate a Facebook / Twitter post with an image from a different url?

Tags: javascript, facebook, twitter

I was wondering if it was possible to prepopulate a Facebook post / Twitter post to include an image that is selected from an external site?

In the past I have implemented sharing links on Facebook using for example: `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=${pageUrl}`

and for Twitter:
`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=${pageUrl}`

However I don't want to share a link, instead I want it to share an image that is clicked from a different site. Is this possible to do? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: no, you would have to use the grapj api to post a photo (if that is still possible), but in a sharing process, you can only use images provided by the og:image tags of the page.

Comment: @andyrandy thanks for your response, I know which image it is, as it's the same image every time, and I can include that image in the meta tag of my site if that's what you mean?

Comment: well, if you can include the image, then just do that :) - should be no problem with that, it always has to be an absolute image url anyway.

Comment: You could share the image URL directly - but then users clicking on it, will only be lead to that URL. Or you could share the URL of a document that _you_ are in control of, with all the relevant OG meta data for title, description and image set - and then redirect actual real users arriving there after clicking the image in the Facebook post, to a different website using JavaScript ...

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible if you can edit the page source - just use the absolute URL of the image on another domain as `og:image` tag, and as `twitter:image` tag for Twitter.

Comment: So if I set up the correct meta data as you described, clicking an image on my site has the capability to load facebook and place that image in a post (then the user would have to submit it?) Do you know of any examples anywhere that I could refer to? Thanks for your help!

Comment: just use the sharer.php, as you intended

Comment: are there no additional params I need in order to render the image in the facebook post before sharing?

Comment: no, not really...you can also use the sharing debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: I will have to try that out, i'm still trying to understand how just adding the meta tag will automagically prepopulate a status, but maybe it just.. works :D. Thanks @andyrandy for helping

Comment: yes, that is exactly how it works :)